# Will the IAEA or another third party investigate the attacks on Zaporizhzhia Nuclear Power Plant?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nuclear-energy

There is a lot of talk about Zaporizhzhia Nuclear Power Plant and the IAEA now being on scene. With the IAEA there, will they make a determination about who has been attacking the nuclear plant? If they wont, does the UN or another international agency investigate this? Or do attacks on nuclear facilities in war zones get reduced to hearing each side blame the other?

Answer (score 4):

No, I recall reading Lavrov said the IAEA will be shown the ["Ukrainian bombing, shelling"](https://tass.com/politics/1500937) damage to the plant (and they [were shown](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75176/who-is-the-guy-with-dark-glasses-pointing-at-the-rocket-tail-end-and-seemingly-d)), but that the IAEA is not mandated to determine themselves who did it.

FWTW, that is confirmed by the IAEA [report](https://www.iaea.org/sites/default/files/22/09/ukraine-2ndsummaryreport_sept2022.pdf) published after the visit, which you can read for yourself, but as al-Jazeera [summarizes](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/9/6/iaea-calls-for-security-zone-at-ukraines-nuclear-power-plant) "The long-awaited report did not ascribe blame for damage at the plant."

Comment: Realistically we can all count ourselves lucky the IAEA is on location.  But, if it was indeed Russia who was misbehaving onsite, there is no way they would have let it in unless they had some control over the resulting PR.